# Populate two columns with value from one cell on condition

Tags: excel, vba

I have a bit of a problem, due to a lack of coding knowledge. I want to create a simple inventory tracking workbook for locations in my shop. In `Sheet 1` I would need a macro to separate values into Columns C and D, depending on what is written into the cell `A1`. Because of barcode scanner I locked  all cells for selection, except `A1` cell . What I would want is, if `A1` values is in this format `X-X-X` (format for bin location, `1-1-1`, `2-3-1`, etc...) to copy to `column C`, and everything else into `column D`.
I have list of bin locations, in sheet2, `range A2:A` if that could help in matching location values. I added in B1 formula to match scaned location with list location.  And here is the code i tried but it won t work as i expect.
Many thanks in advance

Worksheet example screen shot:

[image]

```
Sub razdvoji()
Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim lclr As Long
Dim ldlr As Long




Set wsCopy = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Skeniranje")
Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Skeniranje")

lclr = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

ldlr = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row


If Range("B1") = 0 Then
Range("A1").Copy
Range("D2" & ldlr).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End If

If Range("B1") > 0 Then
Range("A1").Copy
Range("C2" & lclr).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary that you show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you ([No attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)). Reading [Ask] might help you to improve your question.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes i know this website isn t for that,  i found some codes online and used for my needs, for example to fill blanks with values from above, and upload values from this sheet to my master workbook. But i can t find anything how to separate values into two columns.... I woudn t ask for help if i could do this. t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (goes in the worksheet code module):

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim v, v2, cEntry As Range
    
    Set cEntry = Me.Range("A1") 'monitoring this cell only
    If Target.Address <> cEntry.Address Then Exit Sub
    
    v = Trim(cEntry.Value)
    If Len(v) = 0 Then Exit Sub 'cell is empty
    
    v2 = Replace(v, "-", "") 'remove dashes
    
    
    With Me.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp)
        'decide where to put the entry
        If v Like "#*#" And IsNumeric(v2) Then
            'likely location
            .Offset(1, -1).NumberFormat = "@" 'format as text
            .Offset(1, -1).Value = v
        Else
            'box id
            .Offset(1, 0).Value = v
        End If
    End With
    'prep for next entry
    cEntry.ClearContents
    cEntry.Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it work perfect.  I tried somethig by myself but it sucks.  I can continue now my project. Cheers

Comment: I don t want to be greedy, but can u sir pls  check code i posted. What could be changed to work better, when i run the code it makes 10+ blank cells between two value after copy. Its my frankenstein code  :D

Comment: `Range("D2" & ldlr)` should be `Range("D" & ldlr)` or `Cells(ldlr, "D")`  Same goes for `Range("C2" & lclr)`